# Create a dummy for the last observation within each group

Tags: r, date, dummy-variable

Sorry if my question is trivial. I have the following dataset, and I want to create a dummy variable equal to 1 for each unique product_id for the last data. Thanks for your help!

```
df <- structure(list(product_id = c(10000567L, 10000123L, 10000567L, 10000222L, 10000123L, 10000222L)
                , Date = c("12-12-2020", "26-11-2020", "02-11-2020", "09-10-2020", "21-09-2020", "10-09-2020"))
                , class = "data.frame"
                , row.names = c(NA, -6L)
                )
```

Comment: Could you please share a data frame showing your expected output? Thanks. Do you mean for the "last date" or "last data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've interpreted your question correctly this may be one approach with `dplyr`:

```r
df1 <- structure(list(product_id = c(10000567L, 10000123L, 10000567L, 10000222L, 10000123L, 10000222L)
                     , Date = c("12-12-2020", "26-11-2020", "02-11-2020", "09-10-2020", "21-09-2020", "10-09-2020"))
                , class = "data.frame"
                , row.names = c(NA, -6L)
) 

library(dplyr)

df1 |>
  mutate(last_date = ifelse(max(as.Date(Date, "%d-%m-%Y")) == as.Date(Date, "%d-%m-%Y"),1, 0), .by = product_id)
#>   product_id       Date last_date
#> 1   10000567 12-12-2020         1
#> 2   10000123 26-11-2020         1
#> 3   10000567 02-11-2020         0
#> 4   10000222 09-10-2020         1
#> 5   10000123 21-09-2020         0
#> 6   10000222 10-09-2020         0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>